# I don't use antivirus software (just MSE). Am I insane?

Tags: windows, anti-virus, internet-security

I know my way around computers, yet I feel safe using only [MS Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download). I feel that Norton (et al.) are bloated software suites, that aren't *that* useful and suffer from massive feature creep.

Also, now that anyone has at least an ADSL modem, which acts as a router positioned between your machine and the Internet, stopping a lot of nastiness.

I'm also very caution with what I run on my machine, and rarely install anything I do not know.

Am I insane ? Or, to rephrase : On today's Internet, can a (pseudo-)competent user can be considered safe, or reasonably safe, using only the firewall and AV provided by Microsoft ? Or is another piece of software mandatory, such as an anti-malware or anti rootkit ?

Comment: You should maybe ask that question to a psychiatrist. We cannot assert whether you are sane or not. Although putting a space in front of a question mark moves you a little further away from sanity in *my* eyes.

Comment: Considering MSE actually is anti-virus software your question makes no sense.  Furthermore most everyone today is behind either a router or a modem that has router functionality and as such being behind a router does very little.

Comment: yes and no. MSSE started strong, but is now no longer a viable AV system. that said, the strongest protection on the web is (not-so) common sense, and good web-hygiene. so, no, you are not insane per se, but you are taking a risk that may not be necessary. everyone ends up with a bit of bad software now and again.

Comment: I think this is *seriously* opinion based, and also depends on your other habits. I *only* use MSE on my systems for the same reasons and it works for me, but there may be people who need more intrusive or proactive security.

Comment: @Joey I'm fluent in French and English, so I may confuse the languages typographical conventions, from time to time :)

Comment: I'll try to rephrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are insane, but welcome in the club :). I am a software developer, knowing my computer and aware of the risks. Like you I am not installing software I do not know. And my only virus scanner is MS Security Essentials. Until know it seems I have never got a trojan or virus.

I think that the best prevention from viruses and trojans is taking care and not installing software from dubious sources. Think about what you do and what the risks are, and do not click on every link. And for the malicious web pages I might open I have MS Security Essentials. I think this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I'm insane too. It's several years that I don't use antivirus on my laptop (but sometime I must on company ones) I hate useless software running on my laptop: I bought 4 core to use myself not Mr Norton. I keep Windows updated, I don't use IE, I don't run suspicious software downloaded from suspicious website and every while I run Hijackthis. 
Still alive
But it's not good for everyone

Answer (score 1):

> I'm also very caution with what I run on my machine, and rarely install anything I do not know.

This is all well and good, but you never know when something like a new zero-day exploit for Java or your browser is discovered, which can be delivered via an ad in a website.  What about Flash vulnerabilities?  Are you as cautious with your browsing habits on this machine?  Furthermore, are you the only one to use this system?  Do you share your network connection with someone who is not as cautious and might take advantage of a remote exploit in Windows (i.e. the LanManServer service, UPnP-X, etc.)

Hopefully you've uninstalled or disabled any browser Java plugins if you don't need as a part of being cautious, and hopefully you are keeping up to date with Windows and Adobe updates.  Part of being cautious is not having any software you don't need running or installed.

You should at least install and keep updated an offline virus scanner (the free version of  Malwarebytes works this way).  That way you don't have the bloat of a full virus/security suite taking resources, but can run scans at regular intervals when your system is idle or acting funny.

Also I really believe part of a good "antimalware" strategy is keeping regular backups of your data and a fresh and reasonably up-to-date image of your newly installed system.  Sometimes it's best to treat a virus or malware infection as a total system failure and rebuild/reimage from backups rather than spend the time chasing down tools to remove malware.  If you backup your crucial data on a regular basis, the possiblity of malware puts you in a less vulnerable position overall.

Comment: That's really what I was asking ; I know that the "don't launch a .exe you got in the mail" is really old school, and modern threat can even come from reputable websites that have been compromised.

Comment: Yet I'm not convinced that Norton's or McAffee's giant software suite would be able to block a 0 day exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Using antivirus software is not mandatory if you know what you're dealing with, if you suspect you got a virus then check for some with a boot CD, but having a permanent stuff running on your PC can be annoying and useless if you're an experimented enough user...